# how to find mean and frequeny for database values in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using the following code for finding mean and frequency but specifying the values dierctly what i need is to find mean and frequency for the database values. am using codeigniter to this project hope someone could help me. thanks.

```
<script>
  var numberArray=[5,5,1,1], thisTotal=0,thisMean=0;
  // add elements of array together 
  for(var i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++)
  {
     thisTotal+=numberArray[i];}

     // calculate average  
     thisMean=(thisTotal/numberArray.length);
     thisFrequency=(numberArray.length);

     // display result 
     alert(thisMean);
     alert(thisFrequency);
</script>
```

Comment: Use completely the same logic but with PHP - with fetched values from db

Comment: can you have some sample code please

Comment: First provide your tries in PHP and we will help to make it works, if it doesn't :)

Comment: Post your table structure once here.

Answer (score 0):

The same logic can be used in PHP

You can have array(1,2,3,4) and iterate through it with for or foreach loop. The length method is called count() in PHP, so you have to call count($yourArray) in the for loop.

You can use `foreach($yourArray as $key => $value)` so using $key as $i like in your loop.

PHP also provides native array_sum() function which sums all the values in it.

```
<?php
$numberArray=array(5,5,1,1); // predefined array
$thisTotal=0;
$thisMean=0;

/*
 * Array from database assuming you have $mysqli object
 */
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arrayFromDataBase[] = $row;
}

/*
 * numberArray.length (count)
 * Since you use it three times, use the variable assigned to it
 * instead of typing each time numberArray.length /count($numberArray)/
 */
$thisFrequency=count($numberArray);  //change to count($arrayFromDataBase) in order to have array from db;
// the same logic
for ($i = 0; $i < $thisFrequency; $i++) {
    $thisTotal+=$numberArray[$i];
}
// If using associative fetching from database, you would really need foreach()
foreach ($numberArray as $key => $value) {
    $thisTotal+=$numberArray[$key]; 
}
/*
 * or a better logic
 * use one the three provided ways, depending on your needs
 */
$total = array_sum($numberArray);




$thisMean=($thisTotal/$thisFrequency);

echo $thisTotal . "<br />"; // echo $total will give the same result, array_sum() saves your entire loop
echo $thisMean . "<br />";
echo $thisFrequency . "<br />";
?>
```

Read the comments in the code, because if you paste it the whole, it won't give you the desired result, all the ways were provided, and the variables will have triple values. Cut it to fit your needs.

Comment: any other suggestions please

Comment: What is the problem of this suggestion :)

Comment: $numberArray=array(5,5,1,1);  you are using this numberArray na so

Comment: You have not read all my code and comments. I used both examples. A predefined array and a database one. You can use which one you want, and a method for iteration - I provided some.

Comment: hi royal how to give the following mysql code in codeigniter model SELECT gender,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Left-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) left_handed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Handedness = 'Right-handed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) right_handed,
       COUNT(*) total
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP

Comment: am asking this because we use $this->db->select('financial_year');
  $this->db->from('historical_data');
  $this->db->where("financial_year BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
  $this->db->group_by('financial_year'); so am asking

Comment: Well that's another question, I'm not so familiar to CodeIgniter active record. I think reading their documentation might help. You need just to return an array of values. Update your question with how you tried to query the db and what you recieved as response from it.